Spa Root path configuration in .net8
I read a lot about this but none of thew questions here or elsewhere did not help me to achieve the result.
We need to Release and Run our application (ASP.NET API + Angular client) as single application and run Angular application from ClientApp folder.
It seems .net 8 ignores configuration and application is always running from wwwroot (env.WebContentRoot) folder instead.
We had configured this in .net 3.1 and it worked - I tried the same configuration but .net 8 ignores it.
I tried sample with:

registering FileProvider in UseDefaultFiles, UseStaticFiles middlewares
configuration from .net 3.1
and few other modifications of steps mentioned above I found on the internet

None of them helped.
Please can someone give me an advice how to achieve this in .net8?
Thansk a lot
What I tried to do:

I tried to configure SPA application in Production to run from ClientApp folder in .net 8
ClientApp folder should be sibling of wwwroot not child

Configuration from .net 3.1:
string AngularAppRootPath = "ClientApp"

services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => {
                    logger.LogInformation($"AddSpaStaticFiles: configuration.RootPath='{AngularAppRootPath}'");
                    configuration.RootPath = AngularAppRootPath;
                });
 app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

What I expected:

When I run released application to run SPA application from CLientApp folder

Result:

Application tries to run SPA app from wwwroot instead


This is the following configuration I use, that works fine for me. Note that you could have to adapt it to your needs.
Program.cs :
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/Backend/swagger.json", "Backend");
    });

    app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
else
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    var customWebRootPath = Path.Combine(app.Environment.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp", "dist");
    var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(customWebRootPath);

    app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html", new StaticFileOptions { FileProvider = fileProvider });
    app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions { FileProvider = fileProvider });
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { FileProvider = fileProvider });
}

And in your API.csproj :
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
        <SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:44123</SpaProxyServerUrl>
        <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
        <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
        <Configurations>Debug;Release;Staging</Configurations>
        <Platforms>AnyCPU</Platforms>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
        <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
        <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
        <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules')">
        <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
        <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
            <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
        </Exec>
        <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
        <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
        <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
        <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
        <Exec Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Staging'" WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --configuration staging" />
        <Exec Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'" WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --configuration production" />

        <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
        <ItemGroup>
            <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**" />
            <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
                <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
                <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
                <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
            </ResolvedFileToPublish>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>

I use a proxy for dev environment, based on the base template when you create your .NET + Angular web app with visual studio.

Sorry for delayed answer. I was overhelmed. Your solution helped me to solve the problem now we are able to configure SPA app to be able to running from subfolder ClientApp. I tried all your suggestions before except this one: app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html", new StaticFileOptions { FileProvider = fileProvider });

No worries, happy to help :)
In my case that line solved a problem I had when deploying my app on an Azure Linux App Service, where the system architecture is different, and the app wasn't able to find the files once it was deployed

I don't know if can be util, but I have in program.c -In .NET 8 you can not to have a have no Startup.c, you only need a program.c-
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
     builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(o =>
            {
                o.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";

            });
     ...
     app.UseStaticFiles();
     ...
     app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

     if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
     {
          app.UseSpa(spa =>
          {
              spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
              spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start:es");
          });
     }
}

in ClientApp is where I have the Angular app (the angular.json, package.json, the src directory, the node_modules directory...)
When build generate the code in ClientApp/dist, and when publish
In wwwroot I have files that need to read from others places, the favicon.ico, a css that read from index.html...
